# В базе данных что правильнее хранить путь файла с названием, или только название?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных, laravel

В частности в документации  [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#file-uploads)

приводится пример `$path = $request->file('avatar')->store('avatars');`

где говорится что потом можно сохранить путь файла в базе данных,

Но как  правильнее будет , хранить путь к файлу или только название файла,
и как понять в каком случае что использовать ?

Comment: Что тебе надо, то и используй.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Давайте скажу свою практику, а вы там сами определите, что и на сколько подходит под ваше приложение и под идеалогию ларавела. Возможно просто расскажу свой метод который является одним из подходов при работе с файлами.

Путь к картинке делится на 3 части, условно можно обозначить так:

`директория`/`каталоги`/`имя файла`

---

**Пример:**

`/uploads/avatars/2018/10/20/a_mine.jpg`, где:

**директория** - `/uploads/avatars/`

**каталоги** - `2018/10/20/`

**имя файла** - `a_mine.jpg`

---

Смысл `директории` - это разделить вложения по смыслу, например: аватарки, для новостей, для блога, для рекламы, какие-то системные файлы и т.д.

Смысл `каталогов` - как-то рассортировать файлы, чтобы в одной папке не было много файлов, ибо если у нас в папке будет 10к картинок, то запрос на получение - будет долгим. (P.S. Есть какие-то лимиты, сколько рекомендуется хранить файлов, я не вспомню точно, если будет интересно - загуглите, но там не так уж и много).

Смысл `имени файла` - последний этап при идентификации файла. Думаю тут все понятно :)

---

**Что и как хранить:**

---

`Директорию` в базе хранить не стоит, это константа она у вас в проекте где-то должна быть задана, условно, эта константа представляет собой массив, где ключ - алиас директории, а значение - путь. Ну наглядно:

```
[
    'avatars'    => '/uploads/avatars/',
    'blog'       => '/uploads/blog/',
    'news'       => '/uploads/news/',
    'attach'     => '/uploads/attach/'
]
```

**Максимум** что вы можете хранить в таблице, это `название алиаса`, чтобы понимать к чему принадлежит файл и **только в том случае**, если у вас в таблице файлы из нескольких директорий (*что логично*). Например: общая таблица где все файлы из всех директорий.

---

Вот с `каталогами` и `именем` другая басня. Их конечно стоит хранить в таблице, но хранить стоит **отдельно** друг от друга. Может в БД и больше места занимать будет (но на дворе 2к18, с памятью на винте проблем нет), а в замен вы получите более гибкий инструмент для работы с этими файлами.

---

P.S. Стоит ли хранить `расширения файлов`? А вот тут уже спорный вопрос. Зависит от целей, если будет какой-то фильтр для фильтрации по типу - возможно и стоит добавить если у вас очень очень много файлов. Если нет, то на `php` есть функция для получения расширения файла, а со стороны бд, поиск можно осуществлять и штатными средствами. В любом случае если вы не храните расширение, в любой момент добавить эту возможность - не проблема.